# Flutter multi pages on single class

Tags: flutter, navigation, widget

is there a way to give the first item of bottom navigtaion bar multi pages ? i tried to make multi widgets on the first item class and call the widgets on button onPressed but the bottom navigation bar disappears,

Comment: see the example here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html

Comment: already saw it, not what i'am looking for

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you exactly want to implement .but you can try this if it works for you.

```
class TabsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = 'tab-screen';

  @override
  _TabsScreenState createState() => _TabsScreenState();
}

class _TabsScreenState extends State<TabsScreen> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;
  List<Map> tabPages = [
    {
      'page': FirstScreen(),
    },
    {
      'page': SecondScreen(),
    },
    {
      'page': ThirdScreen(),
    }
  ];

  void _selectPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: tabPages[selectedIndex]['page'],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedItemColor: Colors.orange,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        currentIndex: selectedIndex,
        onTap: _selectPage,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home,
                size: 30,
              ),
              label: 'FirstScreen'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.restaurant,
                size: 30,
              ),
              label: 'SecondScreen'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.settings,
                size: 30,
              ),
              label: 'ThirdScreen'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```